# Link ManyToManyFiled with the corresponding Model API

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am having two models "Book" and "Authors". I am having Author details in "Author" model. I am creating "Books" by using API. I want to link the "Author" with "Book" using "Author_id".

I have tried following code.

models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   author = models.ManyToManyField(Author,related_name='author')
```

views.py

```
 class BookListView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, 
        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py:

```
  class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Author
           fields = ('name', )

  class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      assessments = AuthorSerializer(many=True, required=False)

      class Meta:
         model = Book
         fields = ('name', 'authors')


       def create(self, validated_data):
          print(validated_data)
          authors = validated_data.pop('authors')
          book = Book(**validated_data)
          book.save()
          return book
```

I am having following Authors in "Authors" table.

```
  id        name
  1         Alex
  2         John
  3         Bob
```

Sample JSON FIle for creating Book:

```
   {
     "name":"Product 002",
     "authors":
        [
          {
            "author_id":2
          },
          {
            "author_id":1
          }
        ]
    }
```

The following error will comes while saving book.

```
    {
      "authors": [
         {
            "name": [
               "This field is required."
           ]
         },
         {
            "name": [
               "This field is required."
             ]
          }
       ]
   }
```

Json File 2:

```
  {
     "name":"Product 002",
     "authors":
        [
          {
            "name": Alex,
            "author_id":1
          },
          {
            "name": "John"
            "author_id":1
          }
        ]
    }
```

The following error will comes while saving book.

```
    {
      "authors": [
          {
            "name": [
                  "author with this name already exists."
             ]
          },
          {
              "name": [
                  "author with this name already exists."
              ]
          }
      ]
   }
```

Please Help me to solve the problem. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a `name` for the authors while creating the book, because book serializer expects an AuthorSerializer, which expects `name` field (`fields = ('name', )`).

You can do the following 3 solutions:

1. Give what your seralizers expect, change your request body like this:

```py
{
     "name":"Product 002",
     "authors":
        [
          {
            "author_id":2,
            "name":"John"
          },
          {
            "author_id":1,
            "name":"Alex"
          }
        ]
}
```

2. Edit `AuthorSerializer` so that it does not expect `name` but only `id`:

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Author
           fields = ('id', )
```

3. Change `BookSerializer` so that it seralizes authors only by id:

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Authors.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'authors')
```

Your request body would be:

```py
{
     "name":"Product 002",
     "authors": [1, 2]
}
```

Comment: I have tried the follwing JSON file also.

{
    "name":"Product 002",
    "authors":
    [
        {
         "name":"Alex",         
                "author_id":1
        },
        {
         "name":"John",         
               "author_id":2
        }
    ]
}

It throws following error.

{
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": [
                "author with this code already exists."
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": [
                "author with this code already exists."
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have shown 3 different solutions for you.

Comment: Actually It doesn't link author with book. I will create new author while giving author name in request body. Kindly help me to avoid new creation of authors

Comment: If you want to create new author in the body, you need to delete the existing authors from the database first, or give new authors in your body. As far as I see you are giving author ids that already exists in your database.

Comment: No, I don't want to create new author. I want to just linking the Author model with Book by giving Author name in request body. Author names are already created with separate API.In my API, I want to link existing authors with Book

Comment: No, I will Provide existing Authors which is already saved in DB . I want just link author with Book by using existing "Author" name in request body

Comment: Please try my 3rd solution.

Comment: While using 3 rd solution, Can I add name instead of id in request body.
authors: ["John", "Alex] instead of authors: [1,2]

Comment: No you need to pass the primary key of the Author objects. Name is not unique, therefore its not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution.
you will have to change your serializers.py

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('id', 'name', )

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors= serializers.SerializerMethodField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'authors')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        book = Book(**validated_data)
        book.save()
        return book

    @staticmethod
    def get_authors(obj):
        return AuthorSerializer(obj.author.all(), many=True).data
```

By declaring

```
authors= serializers.SerializerMethodField(required=False)
```

you can pass the primary keys of authors in list(in ManyToManyField, it's type is set not List, but can send list to store authors) and while return json serialized data with list of author's id and name.

Your json request body would be:

```
{
     "name":"Product 002",
     "authors": [1, 2]
}
```